# Nim game - splitting stacks to 1

Tags: game-theory

We have an impartial game that works like this. We start with a pile of 10 coins. The player who starts splits the pile into two piles (he can choose sizes). The players then move in turns. At each turn a player selects a pile of size larger than one and split the pile. (To state it clearly, a pile of size one can never be used). The first player who cannot move loses the game.

Who wins this game? What is the optimal strategy?

Can this be generalised to the case with a pile with n coins?

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts.  A good start on problems like this is often to take smaller numbers, and try to notice patterns.

Comment: Note that your game is very similar to [Grundy's game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grundy%27s_game#:~:text=Grundy's%20game%20is%20a%20two,which%20can%20be%20split%20unequally.), though that one stops when only piles of size $1$ or $2$ are left.

Comment: Like all impartial games this is Nim in disguise.  You need to figure out what nimber represents each size of pile.  Start from the small ones.  $1$ is losing, so it is the zero position.  $2$ can move to $1$, so it is $*1$ and so on.  You might see a pattern, or $10$ is small enough you can just do it all the way by hand.

Comment: @RossMillikan: Could you check whether I misunderstood the problem or made a silly mistake in my answer? It seems unlikely that you wouldn't have seen this if it's correct :-)

Answer (score 0):

The game ends when all $n$ coins are in $n$ separate piles. It starts with one pile, and each move increases the number of piles by $1$. Thus the game ends after $n-1$ moves, the first player wins if $n$ is even and the second player wins if $n$ is odd. Strategies are irrelevant; the result is independent of the moves the players make.